# Share Windows/MacOS links with colleagues

Tags: macos, network, windows, smb, links

Is there an easy possibility for Windows/MacOS link conversion to share links with colleagues?

I have a windows link for e.g.:

```
\\networkshare\folder\file.txt
```

and i want to convert to:

```
smb://networkshare/folder/file.txt
```

in our daily workflow. It is very annoying to convert the link manually several times a day

I've already tried some applescripts but thats not an applicable solution for me. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What makes AppleScript solutions not applicable in your case? Or, in other words, how does a solution need to work in order to be applicable?

Comment: Thanks @nohillside, there is a nice option in the answers of the linked question with the LinkConverter app. If i understood the app i just have to copy the link and the app autodetect and converts it. With the existing applescripts I mostly miss a function or it doesn't work with all links.